# Strain field rotational invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

How it can be seen that the quantity 
$$u_{ij}={1\over2}(\partial_iu_j+\partial_ju_i)$$
is rotationaly invariant?
I've tried to use 
$$u_i=R_{ij}u_j',$$
where $R_{ij}$ is the rotation matrix.
Here is my attempt:
$$ {{\partial u_j} \over{ \partial x_i}}={{\partial u_j} \over{ \partial x'_k}}{{\partial x'_k} \over{ \partial x_i}}= {{\partial R_{jl}u'_l} \over{ \partial x'_k}}R^{-1}_{ki}= R_{jl}{{\partial u'_l} \over{ \partial x'_k}}R^{-1}_{ki} $$
where I have used $x'_k=R^{-1}_{km}x_m$.
So for the symmetric combination:
$$2u_{ij}= R_{jl}{{\partial u'_l} \over{ \partial x'_k}}R^{-1}_{ki}+R_{il}{{\partial u'_l} \over{ \partial x'_k}}R^{-1}_{kj}$$
which looks right, but I don't know how to proceed.
I guess the statement I'm trying to prove is just incorrect because its obvious this is not an isotropic tensor in general case. It works only for
 $${{\partial u'_l} \over{ \partial x'_k}}= \lambda\delta_{lk}$$ and $u_{ij}$ proportional to  $\delta_{ij}$

Comment: Please show us the details.

Comment: @ChesterMiller done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rotationally invariant. It's a *tensor* after all, not  a   scalar.

Answer (score 0):

let us denote rotated system with primes
$$u'_{ij}={1\over2}(\partial'_iu'_j-\partial'_ju'_i)$$

We have transformation rule
$$u_i'=R_{ij}u_j.$$ From above relation I guess the transformation rule for derivatives is
$$\partial'_i= \partial_i R^{-1}_{ij}.$$
Plug in the relations
$$u'_{ij}={1\over2}(\partial_i R^{-1}_{ji}R_{ji}u_j-\partial_j R^{-1}_{ji}R_{ji}u_i)$$
which gives back 
$$u'_{ij}={1\over2}(\partial_iu_j-\partial_ju_i)$$
Fix indices yourself and find some way to prove
$$\partial'_i= \partial_i R^{-1}_{ij}.$$

Comment: from your derivation it follows that not only the symmetric combination, but the derivatives separatly are rotationaly invariant, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Derivates are not rotationaly invariant. They do transform and I have given their possible transformation rule.  What do you think $\partial'_i= \partial_i R^{-1}_{ij}.$ is?